# Как в Git diff увидеть изменения в файлах, которые только подготовлены для commit?

Tags: git, git-diff

Подскажите, как в `git diff` увидеть изменения в файлах, которые только подготовлены для `commit`?

Comment: Если система Windows, то лучше установить Tortoise git и не париться.

Comment: @Lucky

Смотрю вы уже отмучились, раз такое советуете?

Comment: @deterok Мой вариант: Если система Windows, то лучше установить Linux и не париться.

Answer (score 7):

`git diff --cached`

или

`git diff --staged`

Comment: И да, zsh с oh-my-zsh рулит при работе с git

Comment: Ничего не выводит ни первый, ни второй вариант.

Comment: Так, вы что-то не так делаете.

Допустим, я имею некоторые изменения, которые еще не проиндексированы для следующего коммита.

Для их просмотра будет достаточно `git diff`, а `git diff --cached` ничего не выводит.

Далее я индексирую изменения `git add main.qml`

Теперь `git diff --cached` выводит проиндексированные изменения связанные с файлом main.qml.

Покажите вывод `git status`.

Comment: Я хочу вывести изменения в файл, делают это так 

git diff --cached > last.txt 

или 

git diff --cached > last.txt 

файл пуст.

Home@HOME-PC /C/xampp/htdocs (master)

$ git status

On branch master

Changes not staged for commit:

  (use "git add <file>..." to upda

te what will be committed)

  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   www/css/style.css

Untracked files:

  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        www/js/contact-script.js

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: *Changes not staged for commit*

А вы говорили, что хотите вывести то, что войдет в коммит.

Тогда здесь cached уберите. Просто git diff в данном случае используйте, либо добавьте файлы в индекс.